# How to clear selected value from RadAutoCompleteTextView

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a `RadAutoCompleteTextView` with remote data look like below

```
<StackLayout>
    <RadAutoCompleteTextView #autocomplete [items]="dataItems" suggestMode="Suggest"
        displayMode="Plain">
        <SuggestionView tkAutoCompleteSuggestionView suggestionViewHeight="300">
            <ng-template tkSuggestionItemTemplate let-item="item">
                <StackLayout orientation="vertical" padding="10">
                    <Label [text]="item.text"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ng-template>
        </SuggestionView>
    </RadAutoCompleteTextView>

    <Button text="clear" (tap)="clear()"> </Button>
</StackLayout>
```

On button click, I want to clear autocomplete's selected value and focus for user input. (As if we click X button at end of autocomplete from UI)

I tried below but not working. Here is the playground [link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=jKqJTx).

```
<Button text="clear" (tap)="clear();autocomplete.value = ''">
this.autocomplete.NativeElement.value = '';
this.autocomplete.active = [];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have set the `displayMode` to `Plain`, you can clear the value by resetting the `text` attribute.

```
this.autocomplete.autoCompleteTextView.text = "";
```

where `this.autocomplete` is `RadAutoCompleteTextViewComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

another option is to use

```
this.autocomplete.autoCompleteTextView.resetAutoComplete();
```